# EditText with NestedScrollView not working OnFocusLostListener

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-nestedscrollview

I have an extension of EditText that i call on my onCreate activities to hide keyboard when edittext looses the focus:

```
fun EditText.hideSoftKeyboardOnFocusLostEnabled(enabled: Boolean) {
val listener = if (enabled)
    OnFocusLostListener()
else
    null
onFocusChangeListener = listener
```

}

So on my onCreate i call:

```
myEditText!!.hideSoftKeyboardOnFocusLostEnabled(true)
```

The problem is that now i have an activity where the edittext is inside a NestedScrollView and this don't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                 tools:context="com.liderasoluciones.smt.presentation.enviarmultimedia.EnviarMultimediaActivity"
                 android:clickable="true"
                 android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView">

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                          android:orientation="vertical"
                          tools:context="com.liderasoluciones.smt.presentation.enviarmultimedia.EnviarMultimediaActivity">

                <TextView android:id="@+id/enviarMultimediaLblEmpleado"
                          android:text="Empleado"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <Spinner android:id="@+id/enviarMultimediaListaEmpleados"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/enviarMultimediaLblMatricula"
                          android:text="@string/LICENSE_PLATE"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/enviarMultimediaActivityMatricula"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:hint="@string/EX_LICENSE"/>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/lblOT"
                          android:text="OT"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


                <Spinner android:id="@+id/listaOTS"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/enviarMultimediaActivityImagenes"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <Button
                        android:text="@string/enviar"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/enviarMultimediaActivityBtnEnviar"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I added the NestedScrollView due to the RecyclerView where i have inside a cardview. Without the nestedscrollview, the cardview uses the rest of the device available heigh (with a scroll) and later the button doesn't appear. Witht he nested scrollview the view works as a want (works like a unique scroll for the whole window), but breaks me the option to hide the keyboard when the user changed the focus form the edittext to other element.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/contentEnviarMultimediaConstraintLayout"
            >

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/contentEnviarMultimediaImagen"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:contentDescription="Imagen a enviar"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/android_logo" android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="left|center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/contentEnviarMultimediaConstraintLayout"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/contentEnviarMultimediaConstraintLayout"
                android:id="@+id/contentEnviarMultimediaProgressBar"/>

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/contentEnviarMultimediaEliminarImagen"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:contentDescription="Eliminar" app:srcCompat="@drawable/eliminar"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

So is there a way to maintain the nestedscrollview and still detect the lost focus of the edittext.